# NoMethodError for nil:NilClass on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I have a Model called *Categories*, which I wanna display. Therefore I have inputed the following statement in the *pages/home.html.erb*

```
<%= render 'categories/index.html.erb' %>
```

Now whenever I run the server I get a *NoMethodError* for the line :

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
```

This is the full *index.html.erb* file of the categories view:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Categories</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @categories.each do |category| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= category.title %></td>
        <td><%= category.price %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', category %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_category_path(category) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', category, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Category', new_category_path %>
 <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Categories</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @categories.each do |category| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= category.title %></td>
        <td><%= category.price %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', category %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_category_path(category) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', category, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Category', new_category_path %>
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Categories</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @categories.each do |category| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= category.title %></td>
        <td><%= category.price %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', category %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_category_path(category) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', category, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Category', new_category_path %>
```

Can someone help me understand why this is not working?

Comment: @spickermann I do not think so! how could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to render the `categories/index.html.erb` partial on your homepage too, then you must initialize all variables that are used in that partial.

Because you use `@categories` in that partial you will need to add the following to your controller action. I assume that you have a `PagesController` with a `home` method already.

```
# in app/controllers/pages_controller.rb
def home
  @categories = Category.all  # <= Add this line
end
```

Comment: thank you so much for the answer! now I get an error saying "undefined method `category_path' for #<#<Class:0x000000000bcc13b0>:0x0000000007d1cbb0>" for the line " <td><%= link_to 'Show', category %></td>" do you understand how I could solve this? I am in desperate need

Comment: I would try to replace `link_to 'Show', category` with `link_to 'Show', category_path(category)`. If that doesn't work I suggest asking a new question because this issue not related to the original question. You might want to add your `config/routes.rb` to the new question.